# Pagespeed warning - Use explicit width and height on image elements

Tags: css, image, tailwind-css, pagespeed, web-performance

I want to set a responsive image in my webpage using tailwind css. I have provided sufficient classes to make it work on different screen sizes. Now I am getting the following error in page-speed.

[image: se explicit width and height on image elements]

How can I eliminate the warning?

Answer (score 1):

### Background

This warning exists to prevent layout shift when images load. Currently, the images have the classes `w-5/6 mx-auto`. This is enough to make the images responsive, but before the images are loaded, the browser doesn't know how tall the image is. Hence, when the image loads, there will be layout shift.

You then need to tell the browser how wide *and tall* the image should be before it loads. There a few ways of doing this.

### With known dimensions

If you know the height of the image, I'd recommend following fromaline's answer.

```
<img src='assets/image/brainstorm.svg' alt='nature' class='w-5/6 mx-auto border' width='300' height='300' />
```

Because we've defined the display width with `w-5/6`, the image will be responsive. The `width='300'` and `height='300'` properties are then used for the aspect ratio.

Here's a link from the Tailwind playground to show you how it's both responsive and removes layout shift: https://play.tailwindcss.com/rjz9ylFNl5?size=482x720

### With unknown dimensions

If you don't know the width and height of your images *and* you need them to be responsive, you need to essentially create a container with a fixed aspect ratio. I'd recommend looking at the [aspect ratio plugin](https://github.com/tailwindlabs/tailwindcss-aspect-ratio).

```
<div class='w-5/6 aspect-w-16 aspect-h-9 mx-auto'>
  <img src='assets/image/brainstorm.svg' alt='nature' class='object-cover w-full h-full'  />
</div>
```

Again, a link to a Tailwind Playground demo: https://play.tailwindcss.com/2zmPJixbrO?size=584x720

Comment: Great answer, made me realise what I needed to fix this issue using Bootstrap instead of Tailwind.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use [Tailwind aspect ratio](https://github.com/tailwindlabs/tailwindcss-aspect-ratio).
It work fine

Answer (score 1):

### To fix this in Bootstrap

First determine the dimensions of the original image - either by looking at the original image you're pulling in or by seeing what size it renders at using browser dev tools. The dimensions themselves aren't important because the browser uses them to calculate an aspect ratio. Add these dimensions using `width` and `height` attributes, and then add the `img-fluid` class to the image:

```
<img src="..." class="img-fluid" width="300" height="300" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Just adding height and width attributes and classes won't work, you have to crop the images as well to its exact dimension. For example if you have set 100px height and width, the image height and width should also be 100px.

Answer (score -1):

You can eliminate this warning by adding `width` and `height` to your images like this:

```
<img loading="lazy" src="assets/image/brainstorm/svg" alt="brainstorm" width="400" height="200" class="w-5/6 mx-auto" />
```

Basically adding `width` and `height` directly to html `img` tag prevents layout shifts, even if `img` is not loaded yet. It's especially important when `img` is lazy-loaded. More info [here](https://gtmetrix.com/use-explicit-width-and-height-on-image-elements.html)

Comment: The CLS will happen even if I specify a fixed height and width and I want my image to be responsive hence added classes. This won't answer my question.